# Resolve left-rescursion

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, left-recursion

Can anybody give me a hint on how to get rid of the left recursion in the following grammar?

$$A \rightarrow B \mid a$$
$$B \rightarrow b \mid C \mid D \mid E \mid F \mid G$$
$$C \rightarrow c \mid A d$$
$$D \rightarrow A e \mid f$$
$$E \rightarrow g \mid B h$$
$$F \rightarrow i \mid A j \mid k$$
$$G \rightarrow l \mid A m \mid n$$

So far I've tried [this](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~kal/images/PLT/PLTelralgorithm.gif) algorithm and [this](http://lab.brainonfire.net/CFG/remove-left-recursion.html) tool. But both are only applicable for smaller grammars and provide practically unusable results (1000's of rules).

Comment: Have you checked other questions about [tag:left-recursion]? There are a couple.

Comment: Did the answer help you, or do you find it unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This explanatory part can be skipped :**

Non-terminal in a Context-Free Grammar can be interpreted as standing
for the set of strings they generate (this is actually one standard
interpretation of CF grammars as string set equations).

For example $A \rightarrow C \mid D \mid a$ may be read as a set
equation $A = C \cup D \cup \{a\}$ where $A$, $C$ and $D$ now stand
for sets of strings and {a} for a singleton set containing the
string "$a$".

Algebraic properties of concatenation and set union on strings and
string sets can be used to transform grammars. In particular, you can
use factorization in ways that are similar to what you do in
arithmetics to make formulae simpler to compute.

Typically, if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are string sets (possibly reduced to a
simgleton, i.e. a single string), then $(A \cup B)C = AC \cup BC$,
i.e. concatenation is distributive for set union, like product is for
sum.

**How to do it**

So, when you transform a CF grammar, you can first reduce the size
with factorization. For that, you may replace some non-terminals by the
right-hand-side of their defining rule, or introduce new non-terminals
when convenient.

$A \rightarrow C \mid D \mid a$
$C \rightarrow c \mid A d$
$D \rightarrow A e \mid f$

can be rewritten as

$A \rightarrow X \mid a$
$X \rightarrow AY \mid Z$
$Y \rightarrow d\mid e$
$Z \rightarrow c\mid f$

There are various ways of using this, but you should be able to use it
to do away with the complexity of your grammar.

*I deliberately did **not** make it as simple as I could have*. My purpose
is only to give you an idea of what can be done.

The correctness of transformations can also be proved directly on
derivations, without having to consider interpretations on string sets
as I did above.

**Complete solution**

Here is a suggested answer. Hoping to simplify presentation, I used
[extended context-free notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Extensions) that allows for regular expressions on
the right-hand side (RHS) of rule. It does not change the practical uses and
properties of CF grammars. You can do it as well by introducing new
non-terminals. This was not really necessary here, but I found it
convenient while doing the transformations. In retrospect, it would be simpler without it.

With this convention the rule $X\rightarrow Y\mid Z$ is equivalent to
$X\rightarrow Y+Z$.  Essentially the operators ¨$+$" and ¨$\mid$" have
the same role.

Starting with your grammar, I first eliminate some non-terminals by
replacing them by the corresponding RHS. I do that in the rule for $B$,
and it gives:

$A\rightarrow B \mid a$
$B\rightarrow (b+c+f+g+i+k+l+n) \mid A(d+e+j+m) \mid Bh$

Then, substituting $A$ by the RHS of its rule:
$A\rightarrow B \mid a$
$B\rightarrow (b+c+f+g+i+k+l+n) \mid (B+a)(d+e+j+m) \mid Bh$

and simplifying

$A\rightarrow B \mid a$
$B\rightarrow (b+c+f+g+i+k+l+n) \mid a(d+e+j+m) \mid B(h+d+e+j+m)$

And going back tu usual CF notation:

$A\rightarrow B \mid a$
$B\rightarrow BX \mid Y$
$X\rightarrow h \mid U$
$U\rightarrow d\mid e\mid j\mid m$
$Y\rightarrow aU \mid V$
$V\rightarrow b\mid c\mid f\mid g\mid i\mid k\mid l\mid n$

Now you only have to remove the left recursion from the $B$ rule in
the usual way, replacing it by:

$B\rightarrow Y \mid YH$
$H\rightarrow X \mid XH$

and you are set.

Comment: Hi @babou .. sry for replying late. Your answer did in fact not help me much since I knew that before. My problem was that I needed to find an efficient way to resolve this left-recursion. If I apply factorization and Paull's algorithm it still results in a few hundred rules which is practically too much for me. I did really appreciate your replay and your help - many thanks for that - though I do not understand why you 'did not make it as simple as you could have'. However, thank you very much!

Comment: ... and after researching for a solution I came up with the conclusion that there is no efficient resolution for this left-recursion. Because of that I switched my whole strategy and I am using a bottom-up parser right now where I can use left-recursive grammars such as the one given above.

Comment: @marcwellman I think there is an efficient resolution (see modified answer). It is an algebraic exercise. What I wonder about is the usefulness of spending so much academic time on top-down parsing. Algebraic training, possibly, as shown by this example? But there should be more interesting topics.

Comment: I did not make my example as simple as I could have because I did not want to do too many things in too few words. Less pedagogical, I think... and I am lazy.

Comment: Hi there again :) thank you very much for your addendum. Right now I am outdoors using my mobile to access this site - but as soon as I am back home I will inspect your solution closely :) Cheers, MW

Comment: I have now implemented your grammar in my LL(1) parser generator and it seems to work although I don't know how to prove that the original left-recursive grammar and your resolved one do define the same language L. But most importantly I am wondering why your approach is so surprisingly simple :) I mean the resolution of left-recursions seems to be a rather hard problem. For example the tool http://cfge.tw-db.info/ give a dozens of rules and the tool http://lab.brainonfire.net/CFG/remove-left-recursion.html is not able to solve it at all. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @marcwellman Your example is actually very simple, because the
recursion is linear, and there is only one. What I tried to tell you is
that you can transform algebraically a CF grammar in a way that is
very similar (not identical) to the transformations you can apply to a
set of polynomial equations. The operations are set union and
concatenation, rather than sum and product. It is fairly simple to
prove that these transformations are correct. It has nothing to do
with recursion removal. Your initial grammar is just a set of seven
equation such as $F=i+Aj+k$, which you use to replace $F$.

Comment: I think I have a rough idea of what you're trying to tell me. However, I am currently working on my code in my parser project .. ahm .. I mean, your code ;) and I will let you know weather I succeeded or not. But so far it seems that you saved me a lot of headache and maybe even my whole project which is rather important for me. So far: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! :)

Comment: The automated tools are indeed not very good. It is obvious from
reading the result that the first one is weak on
factorization. There is probably not much missing to improve its
quality. But I recall that simplifying arithmetic expressions or
factorizing them was not a simple task for early symbolic computation
systems.